# MVVM Change properties of views placed in another view

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm having a problem with setting properties of a View that is placed in a Grid of my MainView. Specifically it's a TreeView explorer for which I want to implement a button that hides it and at the same time sets the ColumnSpan of another view that is next to this one to span on all of the columns. My XAML looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ImageViewer.View.MainView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ImageViewer.View"
         xmlns:model="clr-namespace:ImageViewer.ViewModel"  
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <model:MainViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="62*"/>
            <!--<ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"/>-->
            <ColumnDefinition Width="40*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="195*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <local:FileExplorerView x:Name="fileExplorerView" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,0,0.333">
            <local:FileExplorerView.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:FileExplorerView}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FileExplorerVisibility}" Value="Collapsed">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </local:FileExplorerView.Style>
        </local:FileExplorerView>


        <local:TiledWindowView Margin="0,0,1,0.333">
            <local:TiledWindowView.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:TiledWindowView}">
                    <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="1"/>
                    <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="2"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FileExplorerVisibility}" Value="Collapsed">
                            <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="4"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="0"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </local:TiledWindowView.Style>
        </local:TiledWindowView>
    </Grid>
    <local:MainMenuView Grid.Row="0"/>
    <local:FooterView Grid.Row="2"/>
</Grid>
```

In MainViewModel I invoke OnPropertyChange method and I am 100% sure that it works properly because I tested it with replacing the view with a single TextBlock and I was able to change its properties in XAML using DataTrigger for the same property - FileExplorerVisibility.
I know that there was plenty of entries on this forum about DataTriggers however I could find no answer that answers my problem, none of them work for me. I have never had any problem with finding solutions however this time I even had to create an account to create my first question.
Has anyone any idea what is wrong with this code? Or maybe another approach that I am not aware of would be better in this situation?

MainViewModel

```
        private Visibility fileExplorerVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
    public Visibility FileExplorerVisibility {
        get => fileExplorerVisibility;
        set
        {
            fileExplorerVisibility = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        _aggregator.GetEvent<CollapseEvent>().Subscribe(Collapse);
    }

    public void Collapse()
    {
        FileExplorerVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

FileExplorerViewModel

```
        public RelayCommand CollapseCommand { get; set; }
    public FileExplorerViewModel()
    {
        CollapseCommand = new RelayCommand(CollapseExecute, CollapseCanExecute);
    }

    private void CollapseExecute(object obj)
    {
        _aggregator.GetEvent<CollapseEvent>().Publish();
        //Task.Run(() => CollapseMethod());
    }

    private bool CollapseCanExecute(object obj)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

So the user presses the button in FileExplorerView then the CollapseEvent is published, the MainViewModel subscribes for that event and executes a particular method. I checked this part many times and it works fine. I think the problem is in somewhere in the XAML.

Comment: Can you show your view models too?

Comment: No problem, just updated the question with ViewModels

Comment: So what exactly doesn't work? Any binding errors in visual studio output?

Comment: So everything compiles with no errors however when I click the button to hide the TreeView nothing happens except the FileExplorerVisibility property in MainViewModel changes its value to Collapsed

Comment: I can change properties of TextBlocks, Buttons etc using the same method but changing properties of Views (UserControls) just does nothing

Comment: I see FileExplorerVisibility is part of MainViewModel but each of your views define its own view model which you probably assign to DataContext of corresponding view. So when you bind to FileExplorerVisibility in style for that view - it searches for this property in this view viewmodel, not in MainViewModel. If that is the case - you should see binding errors in Visual Studio "output" window while running application.

Comment: Evk, you're probably right since I got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckDrp.png) message. So I have a mismatch in DataContexts but I am not sure how to resolve this problem. In fact I'm not even sure why the first error appears and what it means.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found a solution. Maybe it is not the best one but it works. I simply placed those views in Grids inside particular columns of a Grid level above and I set the properties of these Grids without manipulating the views. Is this a common practice or there exist a better solution?

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="62*"/>
            <!--<ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"/>-->
            <ColumnDefinition Width="40*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="195*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,0,0.333">
            <Grid.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FileExplorerVisibility}" Value="Collapsed">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Grid.Style>
            <local:FileExplorerView/>
        </Grid>
     </Grid>
```

Evk, Thank You very much for pointing out that the DataContext may be wrong, it helped me a lot.